# Entity Framework Code first foreign key mapping

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 entities:

- Claim (ID, other primirives, one more relation) - Claims table
- ClaimDetail (ID, ClaimID, other primitives, relations) - ClaimDetails
  table

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.ClaimDetails)
                        .WithRequired(x => x.Claim)
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClaimID)
```

A generated query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[ClaimID] AS [ClaimID], 
[Extent1].[UserID] AS [UserID], 
[Extent1].[ClaimTypeID] AS [ClaimTypeID], 
[Extent1].[PermissionID] AS [PermissionID], 
[Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
[Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
[Extent1].[Justification] AS [Justification], 
[Extent1].[Claim_ID] AS [Claim_ID]
FROM  [dbo].[ClaimDetails] AS [Extent1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[ClaimDetailStatusID] AS [ClaimDetailStatusID]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[ClaimDetailStatusID] AS [ClaimDetailStatusID], 
        [Extent2].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn]
        FROM [dbo].[ClaimDetailStatus] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ClaimDetailID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[CreatedOn] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[UserID] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Limit1].[ClaimDetailStatusID] IN (12,11,4,7,13,10)))',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=4106
```

If i left out the mapping then EF will generate another column called Claim_ID1. What is wrong with this? How should I define the relation?

EDIT

```
public class Claim
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SenderID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public UserModel Sender { get; set; } //TODO:

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BossID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public UserModel Boss { get; set; } //TODO:

    public virtual IList<ClaimDetail> ClaimDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClaimItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Justification { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual UserModel Claimant { get; set; }
}


public class ClaimDetail : BaseClaimItem
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int ClaimID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserID {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public override UserModel Claimant {get;set;}

    [Required, Range(1, 5)]
    public int ClaimTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ClaimDetailStatus> ClaimDetailStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ClaimDetailApprovalStep> ClaimDetailApprovalSteps { get; set; }

    public virtual ClaimType ClaimType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't repro. With and without the explicit mapping I only get a `ClaimID` (leaving out the stuff that doesn't compile).

Comment: This: `public virtual int ClaimID { get; set; }` means nothing if you don't map `public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }` to it. See, how i Property mapped it in my answer

Comment: Something strange is going on; i have exported the EDMX and in the XML i see types which aren't exists anymore in my solution not even in excluded files.

Comment: One interface implementation is missing from above. In that interface there is a property which returns a Collection<T>. The [NotMapped]
 attribute was missing now works the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One interface implementation is missing from above. In that interface there is a property which returns a Collection. The [NotMapped] attribute was missing now works the association.

Answer (score 4):

How about try something simple with `Property mapping` rather than `Fluent API mapping`;

```
public class Claim 
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ClaimId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ClaimDetail> ClaimDetails { get; set; }
}

public class ClaimDetail
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ClaimDetailId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Claim"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public int ClaimId { get; set; }

   public string Detail { get; set; }

   public virtual Claim Claim { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API Mapping should be;**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Claim>()
    .HasMany(c => c.ClaimDetail)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ClaimId"));
```

Comment: No luck: ClaimID, Claim_ID, Claim_ID1

Comment: @PeterKiss Please delete the old database from both `Server Explorer and App_Data` and run `Update-Database -Force` again with Property mapping example.

Comment: Can't do that. Code first doesn't mean automated database creation.

Comment: @PeterKiss Well, i assumed you have `Migrations Enabled`. But if you can't do that, and find another way to delete those columns you have already created, you will have to map the desired keys to already existing columns. From the looks of it, `ClaimId` was created when you tried this example, but you already had `Claim_ID` and `Claim_ID1`.

Comment: The ClaimID is part of my model and database the other two columns are generated on the fly somehow. I really don't understand why the framework acting like this.

Comment: @PeterKiss I suspect this happened because, you updated your database without specifying your foreign key column name, then updated again after specifying it in your model. This is why i suggested that you drop the database and run `Update-Database -Force` which will create a new database with the right columns as specified.

Comment: If i try your mapping i get: "Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ClaimID' was already defined. " But i don't see where is it defined.