# Automapper - map parent-child relationship by key from the same collation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have a table structure in DB like this:

```
Id: 1;
Name: 'Question 1',
ParentId: 2
----
Id: 2;
Name: 'Question 1.1',
ParentId: 3
----
Id: 3;
Name: 'Question 1.1.1',
ParentId: null
```

as a result, I need to build a collection of parent-child like this:

```
Id: 1;
Name: 'Question 1',
Children: 
[
 {
   Id: 2;
   Name: 'Question 1.1',
   Children: 
   [
    {
     Id: 3;
     Name: 'Question 1.1.1'
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

I'm using EF to fetch all this data from the DB and build this parent-child relationship on the C# side. The question is if it's possible to build the same relationship with Automapper ProjectTo? If it's not possible with Automapper, any idea how to build LINQ to SQL query for this to aggregate on this data on the SQL side?

Comment: If you are using EF to fetch data from DB, EF actually supports this "cascading" objects into structure/graph. You just need to set that `ParentID` is a foreign key of "which id". [Docs on foreign key](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute). Also ex.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511205/entity-framework-code-first-foreign-key-mapping

Comment: And there is example of what you need to do https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/60320781/entity-framework-core-parent-child-items-in-the-same-model--children-node-returns-null

Comment: @Tatranskymedved is great, but I can't change the DB and can't add a foreign key.